# Diferencia de tiempo transcurrido entre dos horas

Tags: php, mysql

estoy tratando de calcular las horas totales trabajadas del dia por empleado, teniendo como datos, hora de entrada, hora de comida, hora de termino de comida y hora de salida. Quedando estos datos asi:

Entrada: 08:00:00 AM

Comida: 01:00:00 PM

Termino de comida: 01:45:00 PM

Salida de trabajo: 05:00:00 PM

Para calcular las horas trabajadas en el dia, quiero obtener la diferencia que hay entre la hora de entrada y la hora de comida, luego la diferencia entre la hora de termino de comida que es cuando vuelve a entrar a trabajar y la hora del termino del dia de trabajo, esto lo tengo hecho de la siguiente manera:

```
function HorasTrabajadas($h1,$h2,$h3,$h4){

 $horalogin = new DateTime($h1);
 $horalunchstart = new DateTime($h2);
 $horalunchend = new DateTime($h3);
 $horalogout = new DateTime($h4);

 $diferencia1 = $horalogin->diff($horalunchstart);
 $diferencia2 = $horalunchend->diff($horalogout);

 $hora1 = $diferencia1->format('%H');
 $hora2 = $diferencia2->format('%H');

 $horas = $hora1+$hora2;
 return $horas . ' hours';
}
```

El problema es que me esta devolviendo las diferencias mal, por ejemplo de 08 am a 01 pm me devuelve 7. Y tendría que devolverme 5, porque son 5 horas de diferencia. No se porque me esta pasando esto, he buscado y intentado de otras maneras pero sin obtener resultado. Por cierto, los campos de la bd son de tipo time.

Los datos se los paso a la función de esta manera

```
if ($key['login'] != '00:00:00' and $key['lunch_start'] != '00:00:00' and $key['lunch_end'] != '00:00:00' and $key['logout']!='00:00:00') {
  $horas =  HorasTrabajadas($key['login'],$key['lunch_start'],$key['lunch_end'],$key['logout']);
  $form = true;
} else {
  $horas = 'The day is not complete';
  $form = false;
}
```

Cada dato es traído de la base de datos, y cada campo es de tipo time, y se almacena en este formato hh:ii:ss sin mas. Al momento de traerlos mediante la consulta los imprimo luego de recorrer el array que me devuelve la consulta, la forma en la que los imprimo es asi:

```
<?php echo $key['login'] . ' AM'; ?>
```

Y asi sucesivamente con el resto. Y he hecho echo de cada campo y los muestra asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No puedo reproducir el problema. He probado tu código con los datos provistos y me da como resultado 8 (con 5 y 3 horas correctamente) que es correcto. ¿Cuáles son los valores que le pasas `$h1`, `$h2`, `$h3` y `$h4`?

Comment: Los datos que le paso son los que traigo de la base de datos, la hora respectiva de cada campo, no entiendo de verdad porque me esta mostrando mal ese dato. He editado la pregunta para que veas los datos que recibe la función

Comment: ¿Qué valores estás trayendo de la base de datos? Compártelos en la pregunta, no sólo la variable (`$key['login']`) sino también el valor que contiene. Como puedes ver en este [PHPFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/3k18-ynx4), con la información provista en la pregunta, el código funciona sin problema.

Comment: Porque la causa real va a ser que en la pregunta estás diciendo que los valores son "01:00:00 PM" cuando realmente de la base de datos sólo te llega "01:00:00" (en cuyo caso sí habrá problemas por lo que comenta Kevin Mora en su respuesta). Si es así, debes compartir en la pregunta cómo lees las horas en la base de datos, para que podamos ayudarte a identificar la  manera correcta de hacerlo y con ello la solución.

Comment: Ya he editado Alvaro

Comment: ¿Qué formato tiene cada campo en la base de datos? ¿cómo lees los valores de esas horas desde la base de datos?

Comment: Tipo TIME cada campo. Los leo normal, solo le concateno el AM O PM para mostrarlo. Pero imprimo directamente el campo que viene en este formato 08:00:00

Comment: Noto que en el PHPFiddle que pasaste, a la funcion le pasas los parametros cada uno con AM O PM, creo que eso es lo que me esta fallando

Comment: ¿Cómo sabes entonces que 01:00:00 es la 1 de la tarde o de la mañana? ¿En tu base de datos pone 1 o 13 cuando lo buscas? ¿cómo estás leyendo los valores? Te quiero ayudar, pero es que me está costando mucho obtener la información más básica para poder llegar a la raíz del problema.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77494/discussion-between-alejo-mendoza-and-alvaro-montoro).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alejo, según los datos que tú das:

```
Entrada: 08:00:00 AM
Comida: 01:00:00 PM
Termino de comida: 01:45:00 PM
Salida de trabajo: 05:00:00 PM
```

El trabajador ha laborado un tiempo total de **8 horas y 15  minutos**.

Una forma de hacer los cálculos es mediante diferencias en segundos, tomando un timestamp de los objetos.

Observa este código... en los comentarios muestro lo que he dicho más arriba.

También me he basado en `DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i A', $h1)` para crear los objetos fecha como los has presentado en la pregunta. Eso puede variar, dependiendo de cómo estén almacenados los datos en la base de datos.

```
$h1="08:00:00 AM";
/*Si entras a las 8 tenemos horas trabajadas:
 *  1  de 08 a 09
 *  2  de 09 a 10
 *  3  de 10 a 11
 *  4  de 11 a 12
 *  5  de 12 a 13 y a las 13 paras a comer...
*/

$h2="01:00:00 PM";
$h3="01:45 PM";

/*Retomas el trabajo a las 13:45
 *  - recuerda que llevas 5 horas de trabajo
 *  más los 15 minutos hasta las 14
 * ahora seguimos contando
 * 6  de 14 a 15
 * 7  de 15 a 16
 * 8  de 16 a 17
*/
$h4="05:00:00 PM";
/*¡Al fin las 5...!
 * Trabajaste 8 horas y 15 minutos
*/
echo HorasTrabajadas($h1,$h2,$h3,$h4);


function HorasTrabajadas($h1,$h2,$h3,$h4){

    $horalogin = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i A', $h1);
    $horalunchstart = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i A', $h2);
    $horalunchend = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i A', $h3);
    $horalogout = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i A', $h4);

    $totalLunch = $horalunchstart->getTimestamp() - $horalunchend->getTimestamp();
    $totalAtWork = $horalogin->getTimestamp() - $horalogout->getTimestamp();
    $totalWorking = $totalAtWork-$totalLunch; 

    $timeWorking    = gmdate("H:i", abs($totalWorking));
    return "Trabajaste: $timeWorking";
}
```

**Resultado:**

```
Trabajaste: 08:15
```

Comment: Ha funcionado perfectamente @A. Cedano. El problema mio es que al momento de guardar las horas en el campo, no me guarda el AM O PM según la hora. Cada campo es de tipo TIME, y en el $_POST de cada hora recibo 1:45 PM y en el campo se guarda solo 01:00:00. Supongo que es por la configuracion de la base de datos, que corta todo lo que no sea con el formato h:i:s y por eso no me guarda el AM O PM

Comment: @AlejoMendoza no es conveniente guardar AM/PM. Si el campo es del tipo `TIME`, mejor guarda los datos en un formato 24 horas, por ejemplo: `13:00:00` ... `01:00:00`
, de ese modo tendrás menos problemas y menos código que manipular. Si para hacer los `INSERT` del campo tienes que limpiar los valores o convertirlos, hazlo en ese momento y luego irás sobre ruedas. O sea, debes cuidar minuciosamente la fase de inserción de datos, velando porque cada uno tenga su formato adecuado.

Comment: Alli esta mi problema, el cual debo solucionar. Entonces ya con esto que me has dicho podria hacer esto? DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i A', $_POST['hora'])

Comment: @AlejoMendoza el formato `H:i A` es para crear un objeto con horas como esta: `01:00:00 PM`, si las horas tuvieran el formato `01:00:00` o `13:00:00` entonces tendrías que cambiar la creación de los objetos a algo así: `$fecha = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $h1);`. [En el Manual puedes ver toda la doc sobre `createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.createfromformat.php) y los códigos de formato.

Comment: Perfecto @A. Cedano, me pondre a estudiar el Manual. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda! Top!

Comment: Perfecto @A. Cedano, me pondre a estudiar el Manual. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda! Top!

Comment: Aunque con esto también funcionaría @AlejoMendoza: `$fecha=new DateTime('01:00 AM');` y esto también: `$fecha=new DateTime('01:00 PM');` pero el problema de poner en alguna parte `AM` o `PM` manualmente siempre conlleva  el riesgo error, y el tratar un dato como este por ejemplo: `$fecha=new DateTime('01:00 MA');` haría que el código falle.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77496/discussion-between-alejo-mendoza-and-a-cedano).